# React-bootstrap or mdbootsrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I'm making a small web application. Which package should I use for Bootsrap support? Is one better than the other? Are there things that I can do with one but can't with the other? Or is it just the matter of preference? Which one is recommended more?

Answer (score 1):

If that is a really small web app, and you don't need the JS functions in Bootstrap (i.e. just the CSS part in Bootstrap), then I would just stick with only Bootstrap, instead of react-bootstrap nor mdbootstrap.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

MDBootstrap is the design material of bootstrap. MDBootstrap already supports that, see https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/ there you just need to apply it. I think this is easier than customizing with bootstrap.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Try adding some important piece code while you answer any question.